# TCP Socket. Error no matching function call

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

The following is the error I am receiving as well as the small section of code from with it comes from. Could someone please explain what this error means. I have used this connect call in many other programs successfully and I don't know why it fails here. Thank you!

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'Pds::MonReqServer::connect(int&, sockaddr*, long unsigned int)'



///SETUP TCP SOCKET///

 int tcp_socket_info;
 struct sockaddr_in tcp_server;

    //create socket
    tcp_socket_info = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (tcp_socket_info == -1) {
    printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    //assign values
    tcp_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.100"); //address of sender
    tcp_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    tcp_server.sin_port = htons( 1100 );

    //connects
    if (connect(tcp_socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&tcp_server, sizeof(tcp_server)) < 0) {
    perror("Connection error");
    }
    puts("Connected");
```

Comment: The first argument to `connect` should be a reference, no?

Comment: The code you give dies not include `Pds::MonReqServer` which makes explaining the error message just a little hard.

Comment: Judging by what you're doing, you didn't mean to use Pds... anything.  If you really meant to use the standard `connect()` function, try prefixing it with `::` -- you may still get a link error, but it should be more meaningful.

Comment: @donjuedo Your solution works. ::connect(...) made the compiler use the standar connect function instead of the connect method I had in my class. You can post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you're doing, you didn't mean to use `Pds...` anything. If you really meant to use the standard `connect()` function, try prefixing it with `::`